# How to hook (overload) login function of dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I know how to use Xrm/Web resources in dynamics. I want some function to call while dynamics CRM logs in.

To be specific, I want to login to my system while dynamics crm getting logged in. I tried but I didn't get anything which helps me enable to hook login/logout in dynamics crm.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to hook into the authentication mechanism. Are you using on-premise on Online? If on-premise, you are probably using IFD. Assuming your other application can work with ADFS authentication, then you should be able to set it up so that the user only logs in once but can visit either application.

The other possibility is to use javascript in a web resource. The web resource could be placed on the user's dashboard, so assuming they have the dashboard set as their home page, your web resource javascript should execute right after they log in and land on the dashboard.

Comment: I am using online. But what if they have chosen default as dashboard?